# GCP Service Account can't access IAM operations with permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'm using Terraform to automate a lot of my GCP management because clicking is bad. I've got a "shared services" project that I'm trying to use to manage other projects. I'm trying to setup a new environment in another project and need a service account in the shared services project to manage the resources there. (I don't want to by-hand create a new service account for each project)

I'm trying to create a service account in the new project using the shared services service account. The shared services account has organization-level permissions, but I've been trying to add project-level permissions to fix the issue.

Here's the output of `gcloud projects get-iam-policy newproject` (irrelevant info removed, renamed):

```
bindings:
- members:
  - serviceAccount:terraform@shared-services-####.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/editor
- members:
  - serviceAccount:terraform@shared-services-####.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin
- members:
  - serviceAccount:terraform@shared-services-####.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/iam.serviceAccountKeyAdmin
- members:
  - serviceAccount:terraform@shared-services-####.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/resourcemanager.projectIamAdmin
etag: BwWGI28ti_w=
version: 1
```

Here's the output I get attempting to run a test command:

```
> gcloud iam service-accounts get-iam-policy new-service-account@newproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com --project=newproject --impersonate-service-account=terraform@shared-services-####.iam.gserviceaccount.com
WARNING: This command is using service account impersonation. All API calls will be executed as [terraform@shared-services-####.iam.gserviceaccount.com].
ERROR: (gcloud.iam.service-accounts.get-iam-policy) PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
```

The [permissions reference](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-reference) states that `roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin` provides this permission.

Here's the output that Terraform gives me (I know it's a different operation):

```
Error 403: Permission iam.serviceAccounts.get is required to perform this operation on service account projects/-/serviceAccounts/new-service-account@newproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com., forbidden
```

I did create the new service account by hand for this specific case because I haven't setup the rest of the infrastructure yet (which would create the account as part of its process). I wanted to make sure this worked.

Any ideas? As far as I can tell, I've granted the permissions it's telling me I need. Help?

Edit:
Oh, I checked out [trying the API](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/get), and I get a 403 as my user account, which should have organization admin:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission iam.serviceAccounts.get is required to perform this operation on service account projects/-/serviceAccounts/new-service-account@newproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

I am thoroughly confused

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having a nightmare with GCP roles and permissions and you're issue is almost identical to mine.

Comment: Posted a similar issue: https://serverfault.com/questions/989027/gcp-service-account-roles-do-not-work-correctly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably used a [`google_project_iam_policy`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/google_project_iam.html#google_project_iam_policy) resource incorrectly, and overwrote the default IAM policy configuration for the project with an incorrect policy (don't ask how I know this...)

`google_project_iam_policy` is a *very* dangerous resource in Terraform, and the docs do not sufficiently emphasize how dangerous it is. The problem is that setting the IAM Policy *replaces* your project's *entire* IAM configuration with the IAM policy you define. All the default, auto-created service account permissions get wiped out unless you specifically included them in your policy definition.

It is possible to fix your project, but not easy. You need to find all the service accounts that your project needs, and add the correct permissions. Error output from `TF_LOG=TRACE terraform apply` can guide you. The default project IAM policy should look something like the policy below, though it will differ based on which APIs you have enabled and which Google Cloud features are in use. (policy sanitized with xxxxx replacing project ID)

```
bindings:
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service-xxxxxxxxxxx@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/compute.serviceAgent
- members:
  - serviceAccount:xxxxxxxxxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
  - serviceAccount:xxxxxxxxxxx@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com
  - serviceAccount:terraform-service-account@your-terraform-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/editor
- members:
  - user:owner@example.com
  role: roles/owner
- members:
  - serviceAccount:terraform-service-account@your-terraform-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/servicenetworking.networksAdmin
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service-xxxxxxxxxxx@service-networking.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/servicenetworking.serviceAgent
etag: BwWc0THMaHA=
version: 1
```

If you are getting this error, run `gcloud projects get-iam-policy your-project-name` and see what's missing. In all likelihood, the policy change wiped out your owner role, and roles for the default service accounts (the ones that include your project ID in the name).

**Summary**: if you're using Terraform to manage IAM in Google Cloud Platform, you should generally NOT be using resource `google_project_iam_policy`, unless you are an expert at [hand-writing Google IAM policies](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/policies). If you must use it, before you begin, run `gcloud projects get-iam-policy your-project-name` and save the results so you can see what your IAM policy looked like before you broke it.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with previous answer, just noting that you can view all of the roles that were deleted in IAM -> View Resources. Once there, check the project that you accidentally nuked, click Activity, and each change until you find your super-destructive one. Should be much easier to go through there and add the changes back.